# Open multiple new tabs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a function that should open several tabs, but instead of doing that it opens one new tab and other links comes as new windows, how do I fix it? Thanks. :)

```
    function getLinks(elem){
    var linkai = $(elem).attr("linkai").split(' ');
    for (var i=0; i<linkai.length; i++){
        window.open(linkai[i]);
    }
}
```

Every element of `linkai[]` should come in new tab not new window.

Comment: Other browsers opens it correctly except chrome.

Comment: You are using window.open and that open a new window xD

Comment: So, what should I use? window.open opens new tab in firefox, IE, and chrome, but when opening multiple tabs chrome opens only one tab and other links comes as windows.

Comment: You should try with: window.open(linkai[i],'_new');